# Replicate "ng serve --host NAME --publicHost NAME:PORT" with webpack/react/nginx

Tags: reactjs, angular, docker, nginx

I am now working on an application where the login page is served by docker under `http://DOMAIN_NAME/folder/`.

I am trying to replicate the setup that was used with an Angular app and port it to a React App, this is the command used in `package.json`:

```
...
"start": "ng serve --host DOMAIN_NAME --publicHost DOMAIN_NAME:PORT"
...
```

I did not touch NGINX reverse proxy a lot in the past hence my confusion with this setup.

I am wondering what `--host` and `--publicHost` do behind the scenes and how I can configure `webpack-dev-server` accordingly.